# Interpretation of a generalised mixed-effects model with family = Poisson in R

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, interpretation, poisson-distribution

While looking for the best analysis of my data, I found linear mixed models. I wanted to use them because I have variance by subject and by item, but I only found tutorials for continuous or binomial dependent variables. My dependent variable is a count variable: 12 items, scored as 0, 1 and 2 (incorrect, partially correct and correct). I read that I can use a generalised linear mixed model, using subject and item as random effects, and using family=poisson. My model looks like this:

```
    model <- glmer(Score ~ Var1 * Var2 + (1|Subject) + (1|item), data = mydata, family="poisson")
```

Var1 is low, medium and high.
Var2 is time (day, week and month)

I used summary(model), and got this outcome:

```
    Fixed effects:
                          Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
    (Intercept)          -0.2203     0.1610  -1.685  0.09192 .  
    Var1medium            0.6856     0.2250   2.641  0.00828 ** 
    Var1high              0.4822     0.2010   2.262  0.02371 *  
    Var2week              -1.1509     0.1130  -8.723  < 2e-16 ***
    Var2month             -3.3456     0.2109 -10.835  < 2e-16 ***
    Var1medium:Var2week    0.5808     0.1318   3.914 9.10e-05 ***
    Var1high:Var2week      0.7001     0.1318   4.532 5.85e-06 ***
    Var1medium:Var2month   0.8200     0.2400   2.946  0.00322 ** 
    Var1high:Var2month     0.7898     0.2011   1.633  0.10251
```

If there isn't a straightforward answer, I would appreciate if you could point me out to a good reference of the interpretation of these estimates.

Comment: What exactly is being counted - "incorrect, partially correct and correct" is not a count variable

Comment: It is a memory test of 36 items. At each delay (Var2) the subjects were asked to remember 12 items. If they could remember only half of the item, they got 1 point, and 2 if they remembered the whole item. It could be a continuous variable ranging from 0 to 24 if I average across items, but then I would ignore the between-items variance. Even if it was categorical, I still would need family poisson, I think.

Comment: Is your question about how to interpret the individual regression coefficients you included above? Interpreting these fixed effects part of the model is basically the same as with a typical GLM. If you know how to interpret an interaction effect, you can interpret these coefficients.

Comment: Oh, ok, thanks. I wasn't sure and I didn't want to make a mistake. Thank you!